# Argument out of range

Tags: c#-4.0, csv, import, firebird

I have to import .csv file into firebird database with C#. For this purpose I wrote the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {            
  FbConnection FBConnect = new FbConnection();
  FBConnect.ConnectionString =   global::MTel.Properties.Settings.Default.MTelConnectionString;
  string s1 = "Изходящ разговор Корпоративна група ";
  string s2 = "Изходящ SMS М-Тел ";
  string s3 = "Изходящ SMS Виваком ";
  string s4 = "Изходящ SMS Глобул ";
  string s5 = "Мобилен Интернет ";
  string s6 = "Мобилен Интернет Безплатен Трафик ";
  string s7 = "Мобилен Интернет Vodafone live! в портала ";
  string s8 = "Допълнителни услуги ";
  string s9 = "Изходящ SMS Корпоративна група ";
  string s10 = "Изходящ SMS Допълнителни услуги, нормална тарифа ";
  string s11 = "Изходящ разговор Безплатни разговори ";
  string s12 = "Изходящ разговор Спешни номера ";
  string s13 = "Изходящ разговор Корпоративна група, пренасочване ";
  string s14 = "Изходящ разговор Гласова поща ";
  string s15 = "Изходящ разговор Гласова поща, пренасочване ";
  string s16 = "MUSICALL ";
  string s17 = "Изходящ разговор Обслужване на клиенти *88 ";
  string s18 = "Телевизия и видео ";
  string filePath = "D:\\MTel\\Test.csv";
  Records[] rec;
  CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(filePath), true);
  int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
  string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
  string InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Records(Record_Number, Type_Service, Duration,                              Record_Price) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
  FbCommand FbCom = new FbCommand(InsertQuery, FBConnect);
  try {  
    FBConnect.Open();
    while (csv.ReadNextRecord()) {
      for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
        if (csv[i].ToString() != s1 || csv[i].ToString() != s2 ||
            csv[i].ToString() != s3 || csv[i].ToString() != s4 ||
            csv[i].ToString() != s5 || csv[i].ToString() != s6 ||
            csv[i].ToString() != s7 || csv[i].ToString() != s8 ||
            csv[i].ToString() != s9 || csv[i].ToString() != s10 ||
            csv[i].ToString() != s11 || csv[i].ToString() != s12 ||
            csv[i].ToString() != s13 || csv[i].ToString() != s14 ||
            csv[i].ToString() != s15 || csv[i].ToString() != s16 ||
            csv[i].ToString() != s17 || csv[i].ToString() != s18) {
            if (headers[i].ToString() == "Телефонен/Абонатен номер") {
              FbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("Record_Number", csv[i]);
              FbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();                             
            } else if (headers[i].ToString() == "Услуга и направление") {
              FbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("Type_Service", csv[i]);
              FbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } else if (headers[i].ToString() == "Количество (сек. бр. kB.)") {
              FbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("Duration", csv[i]);
                FbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } else if (headers[i].ToString() == "Такса (лв.)") {
              FbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("Record_Price", csv[i]);
              FbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (FbException FbEx) {
      MessageBox.Show(FbEx.ToString());
    } finally {
      MessageBox.Show("Данни са успешно импортирани в базата данни", "Успешна    операция", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
      FBConnect.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

But for the line

```
FbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'm getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index. Why is that happen?

Comment: Your parameters are unnamed. You will need to use their index, or convert your query to use named parameters. (and what David said).

Answer (score 2):

Your query has 4 parameters:

```
string InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Records(Record_Number, Type_Service, Duration, Record_Price) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

But you only ever add one parameter:

```
FbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("Record_Number", csv[i]);
FbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If you show the stack trace (which you're essentially throwing away in your exception handling, by the way) we may be able to confirm, but my guess is that it's looking for the next parameter that you haven't supplied and that's where it's exceeding index bounds somewhere.

You'll either need to supply all of the parameters your query is expecting to use a different query.  Perhaps you intend to supply default values for the other parameters?  If the database is set up to have default values when none are supplied, that's one thing.  But in this case the query itself is still expecting them.

Comment: I replaced csv[i] with it's actual values, but now I'm getting "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for this line:
FbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("Record_Number", csv[1]);

Comment: @ВладиславНайденов: That just means one of your objects is `null`.  Which one is it?  Also, why did you make that change?  Is your array indexer also causing problems?  It seems like you're just guessing and changing random things in the code instead of following any logical debugging procedure.

Comment: I make the change because csv[1], csv[3], csv[4] and csv[5] are the columns of the .csv file which I want to import in database.

Comment: @ВладиславНайденов: That doesn't address the problem pointed out in this answer, though.  According to the code in the question, you're only adding one parameter to the query, but it's expecting four.  Changing that one parameter or specifying it in a different way doesn't change the fact that you're still only adding one, not four.